# Initialize observable with the result of other observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have 2 requests.

1. `getCurrentBook(): Observable<Book>`
2. `getDetailedInfo(bookId): Observable <BookDetailed>`

They both return observables with information, however to use second request I have to make sure that I received the information from the first one since `bookId` is in the response.

I understand that I could subscribe inside other subscribe, however this solution doesn't seem appealing to me. There must be a much more elegant way.

The existing solution

```
getCurrentBook().subscribe(res => {
  getDetailedInfo(res.id).subscribe(...);
})
```

I get that it should look something like:

```
booksSubs = getCurrentBook().pipe(
  map(res => 
    {this.currentBook = res}
   )
  )
detailedSubs = getDetailedInfo(this.currentBook.id).pipe(
  map(res => 
    {this.detailed = res}
   )
  )

this.subscriptions.push(SOME OPERATOR(booksSubs, detailedSubs).subscribe();
```

But the option higher won't work since I need result of first observable to initialize second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using some of "flattening" operators, for example [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap):

```js
const currentBookDetails$ = getCurrentBook().pipe(
  mergeMap(book => getDetailedInfo(book.id))
);
```